# PHP: Dynamic Drop down with optgroup

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I am developing a drop down menu that uses HTML optgroups for group names that employees are a part of.  Here is the MySQL query and output:

```
mysql> SELECT employees.emp_id,employees.empname,employees.grp_id,groups.groupname FROM employees left join groups on employees.grp_id = groups.grp_id order by groupname asc;
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+
| emp_id | empname    | grp_id | groupname |
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+
|     20 | Employee 2 |     13 | Group 1   |
|     19 | Employee 1 |     13 | Group 1   |
|     21 | Employee 3 |     14 | Group 2   |
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The only issue is, I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to get the optgroup to work correctly.  I've tried countless times, and it's really starting to frustrate me. **The following is pretty much I want the output to be (example):**

```
<select name="dropdownmenu">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option name="20">Employee 2</option>
        <option name="19">Employee 1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option name="21">Employee 3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Basically, the optgroup needs to be the "groupname", the option "name" should be the "emp_id", and the action "option" (drop down item) is the "empname".

I hope this is something that can be done, but really not sure.  Here's the function I have, but it doesn't exactly work well:

```
function getDynGrpList() {
    global $db;

    // $query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY grp_id desc;";
    $query = "SELECT employees.emp_id,employees.empname,employees.grp_id,groups.groupname FROM employees left join groups on employees.grp_id = groups.grp_id order by groupname asc;";
    $employees = $db->GetAll($query);
    $groups = array();

    while ($qa = $employees->GetRows()) {
        $groups[$qa['groupname']][$qa['grp_id']] = $qa['empname'];
    }
    foreach ($groups as $label => $opt) { ?>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo $label; ?>">
<?php   }
        foreach ($groups[$label] as $id => $name) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
        </optgroup>
<?php }
```

**getDynGrpList function as of 3:15AM CST (2/27):**

```
function getDynGrpList() {
    global $db;

    // $query = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY grp_id desc;";
    $query = "SELECT employees.emp_id,employees.empname,employees.grp_id,groups.groupname FROM employees left join groups on employees.grp_id = groups.grp_id order by groupname asc;";
    $employees = $db->GetAll($query);
    $groups = array();
    while ($qa = $employees->GetRows()) {
        $groups[$qa['groupname']][$qa['emp_id']] = $qa['empname'];
    }
    var_export($groups);
    foreach($groups as $label => $opt): ?>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo $label; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($opt as $id => $name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </optgroup>
<?php endforeach;
}
```

**Final Solution (with the help of Felix Kling)**

```
function getDynGrpList() {
    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT employees.emp_id,employees.empname,employees.grp_id,groups.groupname FROM employees left join groups on employees.grp_id = groups.grp_id order by groupname asc;";
    $employees = $db->GetAll($query);
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($employees as $employee) {
        $groups[$employee['groupname']][$employee['emp_id']] = $employee['empname'];
    }
    foreach($groups as $label => $opt): ?>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo $label; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($opt as $id => $name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </optgroup>
<?php endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two for loops are not nested in your code:

```
foreach ($groups as $label => $opt) { ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $label; ?>">
<?php   } <-- wrong here
    foreach ($groups[$label] as $id => $name) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

The result is that first all opt groups are created and then the employees for the last group are added (because `$label` and `$opt` are also available after the loop finished).

You have to nest the loops ([*using alternative syntax for control structures*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)):

```
<?php foreach($groups as $label => $opt): ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $label; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($opt as $id => $name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </optgroup>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Furthermore, I think you have to use the `emp_id`, not the `grp_id` when creating the array:

```
while ($qa = $employees->GetRows()) {
    $groups[$qa['groupname']][$qa['emp_id']] = $qa['empname'];
}
```

Comment: I'm actually getting a blank drop down with the code.  Your code and my code doesn't actually show any drop down menus.  Somewhere in the code, there's an issue, just don't know where.

Comment: @drewrockshard: Make a `var_export($groups)` before the loop and see if the array contains data and what structure it has.

Comment: I updated my initial post.  After adding the var_export($groups), there was no output on that either.  Maybe if you could look at my entire function, maybe you could spot something wrong.

Comment: I pulled the function out of the select form and let it print to the screen.  Here's the error I get: `Fatal error: Call to a member function GetRows() on a non-object`

Comment: @drewrockshard: Mmh. What is `$db`?

Comment: I'm using adodb5 as a MySQL wrapper.  It works for all my other functions (there are about 6 other functions that are using it).  Here's the actual defining of `$db`: `$db = NewADOConnection("mysql");`  From here, it uses the adodb5 libraries.

Comment: Ahh, damn. Figured it out. adodb5 does the `while` loops in this way a different way.  They go about it in a `foreach` approach.  I'll post my solution.