# How to make HTML optgroup dynamically from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my table :

```
| NAME   | Operator   |

| name1  | operator1  |

| name2  | operator1  |

| name3  | operator2  |

| name4  | operator2  |

| name5  | operator2  |
```

and this is my static select optgroup, i set it manually :

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Operator1">
 <option value="volvo">Name1</option>
 <option value="saab">Name2</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Operator2">
 <option value="mercedes">Name3</option>
 <option value="audi">Name4</option>
 <option value="audi">Name5</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

My question is, how to make it dynamically and get the data from my database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132166/php-dynamic-drop-down-with-optgroup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489498/how-to-generate-dynamic-selectbox-with-optgroup

Comment: have you  try or search?

Comment: thx for your references @Shafiqul Islam

Comment: you are welcome