# dynamically create a select dropdown menu with optgroup

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to dynamically create a select dropdown menu with optgroup. the data would come from 2 separate data tables: `activities` and `client_list`

`activities` :

[image: activities table]

`client_list` :

[image]

I need a single dropdown that would display the client name and the product. with `client_name` as the optgroup label and `product` as the option value.

[image]

what I tried doing is I left joined the two tables.

QUERY:

```
SELECT a.client_name, a.product
FROM activities a 
LEFT JOIN client_list c ON a.client_name = c.client_name
ORDER BY a.client_name ASC;
```

This is my attempt at creating the dropdown menu.

PHP:

```
<?php
    $get='SELECT a.client_name, a.product 
        FROM activities a 
        LEFT JOIN client_list c 
        ON a.client_name = c.client_name 
        ORDER BY a.client_name ASC';
    $result=mysql_query($get);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    foreach($result as $results) {
        $row[$results['client_name']][$results['product'] = $results['product']];
    }
?>
```

I've tried the ff: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831941/select-dropdown-php-foreach-loop-with-optgroup-options), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489498/how-to-generate-dynamic-selectbox-with-optgroup), and [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132166/php-dynamic-drop-down-with-optgroup). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

How can I achieve this through php or even jquery? Also, can this be done without joining the table? I saw this [wordpress article](https://mksaravanamk.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/creating-dynamic-dropdown-menu-with-opt-group-from-the-data-in-two-separate-tables-in-mysql-database-in-codeigniter-and-php/) and I think it's exactly what I need but it didn't explain how it was done.

*I would like to note that not all clients in the `client_list` are listed in `activites` so i can't use the `activities` table alone. I would also like to note that I have no choice but to use mysql as the company I'm in still utilizes it. I am aware of the problems with it. Thank you!*